# POWERBI no reconoce las funciones de time intelligence

Tags: powerbi

Quiero hacer **una tabla para compare la evolución de las compras de dos años** distintos (en mi caso, 2019 y 2020).

Para ello he utilizado la función SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR, de tal forma que las funciones que agregaría al gráfico serían:

```
total_purchase_amount = SUM(fact_purchase_order[total_purchase_amount])

total_purchase_amount_LY = CALCULATE([total_purchase_amount],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(dim_date[formatted_date]))
```

donde formatted_date es la “dimensión calendario”

Sin embargo, si paso este resultado a una matriz, **la columna de total_purchase_amount_LY aparece vacía** (como se aprecia en la imagen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tThiF.png)).

¿Alguien podría decirme que es lo que puede estar ocurriendo? Las tablas de fact_sale_order y dim_date están relacionadas a través de un date_ID.

Muchas gracias!

PD: Este mismo problema también me lo ha dado con DATEADD.

Comment: Asegúrate que el tipo de dato de la columna `dim_date[formatted_date]` es de tipo fecha

Comment: Sí, es de tipo fecha. Así que no sé qué puede ser...